# This Parse App does not have a page at the requested URL

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I have a Facebook Canvas application (unity3d app built for webgl). I host it on parse. Upon launch the app on Facebook, I get the error:

**This Parse App does not have a page at the requested URL**

However, I can access my app when I type the parse link directly in the web browser.

Though I put the webgl files in a folder under the public folder and created an express.js file that redirects the get from Facebook, it still does not work.

What should the express.js file contain exactly? Where should it be put (public or cloud or child folder). Do I need the rename the index.html file and move it to a different location as someone suggested?

Lastly, is it normal for .htaccess to be ignored when pushing files through the shell?

Answer (score 2):

According to parse, the hosting only supports HTTP GET by default.(https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-hosting-and-facebook-canvas-apps)

You just need to add this piece of code to your cloud/app.js

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {res.redirect('/');});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

WeiWei's code worked. Here is the full code for app.js or main.js, But, it is recommended to use this code inside app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/', function(req, res) {res.redirect('/');});
app.listen();
```